# Printing to Receipt Printer: Java

Tags: java, swing, printers

I am trying to print a multilne string to a receipt printer, without showing the prompt. 
Currently have this:
First, defining the printer, which name is in a txt file:

```
PrintService[] printers = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
    for (int x = 0; x < printers.length; x++) {
        System.out.println(printers[x]);
        try {
            if (printers[x].getName().toLowerCase().indexOf(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Resources", "Printer.txt")).get(0).toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Good");
                printer = printers[x];
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And then

```
JTextArea toPrint = new JTextArea();   
toPrint.setLineWrap(true);
toPrint.append(text);
toPrint.print(null, null, false, printer, null, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
```

It prints everything, but not how I wanted. It only occupies a bit of the total width:
[image: The receipt]

But I if print the file through windows notepad, it outputs this. The problem is that it doesn't stop printing like in the java program
[image: Supposed to be like this]

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you give us an example of your output and an example of your expected output?

Comment: The Java 2D printing API prints graphically thru the OS print driver. Probably the page width in the printer settings are such wide. Anyway, for POS printing you may use http://www.javapos.com/ (it is old, but still valid).

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Sure the objective would be to be printed the whole width

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Its skipping lines without neccessity

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Gonna update the question

Comment: `if (printers[x].getName()…` 1. Don’t read the same file over and over inside a loop; read it *once* before your loop starts, and store the first line in a String variable. 2. Reading a file named Resources/Printer.txt looks fishy.  You probably wanted `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Resources/Printer.txt")`. 3. Don’t read every line of the file when you only need one line. Create a BufferedReader, read the first line, then close the BufferedReader. 4. Use contains, not indexOf. 5. If you encounter an IOException, stop and exit.  You can’t proceed if you don’t have a printer name!

Comment: @VGR Thanks. People told me to use this method of reading files because its the most recent api

Comment: Yes, the Files class is the most recent API and you should use it—for files.  However, it has many methods (including [Files.newBufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path)), and you should not use a method that reads the entire file, if you only need one line. Also, embedded resources usually are not files.